# Word Search (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am working on a word search program, that would find words in all possible directions. I have already have a solution in mind but I don't know how to proceed with it. Currently I have this :

```
    words=['heya']
    rows= ['eahaehh','allehoh','gohloau','rhelloy','iayoyiu','iiaelah','hlhallo']

for y, row in enumerate(rows):
    for x, letter in enumerate(row): 
        for word in words:
         direction=[(y-1, x-1), (y-1, x+1), (y+1, x+1),(y+1, x-1),(y+1,x),(y-1,x),(y,x+1),(y-1,x)]  
            for p in direction:
                for t in p:
                    for l in word:
                            try:
                                if l==rows:
                                    print('yes')
                            except IndexError:
                                pass
```

So a little explanation the 'direction' contains all the possible directions of a word (left, down-left, right-left and so on). The thing that I can't figure out is how I am to use the coordinates in the 'directions' to search the grid. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I let you a snippet of code here, you should implement the search function **search_word_in_direction** to get this done. I hope this helps you !

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from enum import Enum
import functools

class Direction(Enum):
    NONE = 1
    LEFT = 2
    RIGHT = 3
    UP = 4
    UP_LEFT = 5
    UP_RIGHT = 6
    DOWN = 7
    DOWN_LEFT = 8
    DOWN_RIGHT = 9

def coordinates_in_matrix(coordinate, x_len, y_len):
    y, x = coordinate
    return x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < x_len and y < y_len 

def direction_to_coordinate(direction, x, y):
    if direction == Direction.NONE:
        return (x, y)
    elif direction == Direction.LEFT:
        return (x-1, y)
    elif direction == Direction.RIGHT:
        return (x+1, y)
    elif direction == Direction.DOWN:
        return (x, y+1)
    elif direction == Direction.DOWN_LEFT:
        return (x-1, y+1)
    elif direction == Direction.DOWN_RIGHT:
        return (x+1, y+1)
    elif direction == Direction.UP:
        return (x, y-1)
    elif direction == Direction.UP_LEFT:
        return (x-1, y-1)
    elif direction == Direction.UP_RIGHT:
        return (x+1, y-1)

def get_neighbours_coordinates(x, y, x_len, y_len):
    coordinates_by_direction = {}
    for direction in [Direction.LEFT, Direction.RIGHT, Direction.UP, Direction.UP_LEFT, Direction.UP_RIGHT, Direction.DOWN, Direction.DOWN_LEFT, Direction.DOWN_RIGHT]:
        coordinate = direction_to_coordinate(direction, x, y)
        if coordinates_in_matrix(coordinate, x_len, y_len):
            coordinates_by_direction[direction] = coordinate
    return coordinates_by_direction

def get_directions_to_look_for(rows, x, y, next_character):
    neighbours_coordinates = get_neighbours_coordinates(x, y, len(rows), len(rows[0]))
    directions = []
    for direction in neighbours_coordinates:
        coordinate = neighbours_coordinates[direction]
        neighbour_character = rows[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]]
        #print('[debug] to find: %s, pointer (%s, %s): %s' % (next_character, coordinate[1], coordinate[0], neighbour_character))
        if next_character == neighbour_character:
            directions.append(direction)
    return directions

def search_word_in_direction(rows, direction, x, y):
    # TODO
    return False

word = 'heya'
rows = ['heyaehh', 'ellehoh']

index_to_find = 0
start_character = word[index_to_find]
next_character = word[index_to_find + 1]

for y, row in enumerate(rows):
    for x, cell in enumerate(row):
        current_character = rows[y][x]
        if rows[y][x] == start_character:
            print('We can begin at (%s, %s)' % (x, y))
            for direction in get_directions_to_look_for(rows, x, y, next_character):
                print('Searching in direction: %s' % direction)
                if search_word_in_direction(rows, direction, x, y):
                    print('\nWord exists in start point: (%s, %s) and for the direction %s\n' % (x, y, direction))

print('\nWord search finished')
```